# How to Call javascript function in JSP from JS file

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a situation to call javascript function which is available in JSP from another function inside Javascript(js) file. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if JSP is loaded at first and the other function  (inside js) get's the reference in the context and the time it is called.